# How to create a tab layout with a fixed number tabs, with static elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an activity with a tab layout for my app. My aim is for this layout to have a fixed number of tabs (I'm thinking four, maybe five), each with static elements (labels, textviews, etc.). These elements will be filled with personal data corresponding to the user (like name, age, etc.) that will be taken from a database. My problem is that I can't find how to make this static layout.

I searched in the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), I tried the example in the link and it worked, but I can't figure out how to adapt it into what I'm trying to make.

Could someone give me a basic example of how to make this fixed tab layout?

Comment: Did you also look at the `TabHost` class?

Comment: @Luksprog No, I didn't. I'll give it a look now.

Answer (score 0):

1. In activity, call  *getTabHost()*  to get TabHost object.  Individual tabs will be added to this object.
2. Call TabHost Object's newTabSpec() in order to create/inflate individual tabs.
3. After creating all the tabs by repeatedly performing step #2 above, finally, call addTab() method of TabHost object for the tabs be added and displayed.

   ```
   private void createTabs() {

       TabHost tabs = getTabHost();

       getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, tabs.getTabContentView(), true);

       Resources resources = getResources();

       TabHost.TabSpec tabOne = tabs.newTabSpec("TabOne")
           .setContent(R.id.tabone)
           .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tabone), 
           resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabone));

       TabHost.TabSpec tabTwo = tabs.newTabSpec("TabTwo")
                           .setContent(R.id.tabtwo)
                           .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tabtwo),
                           resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabtwo));

       TabHost.TabSpec tabThree = tabs.newTabSpec("TabThree")
           .setContent(R.id.tabthree)
           .setIndicator(getString(R.string.tabthree), 
           resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabthree));


       tabs.addTab(tabon);
       tabs.addTab(photo);
       tabs.addTab(reservation);
   }
   ```

Comment: Is the above answer helped you? If so, can you please accept the answer?  thanks.

Comment: getTabHost() is a method of TabActivity not Activity. You'll need to extend that instead of Activity for the method to be defined in your object.